# Why it is not Sorting the results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing the problem to debug this code. Given an array of  Player objects, write a comparator that sorts them in order of decreasing score. If or more players have the same score, sort those players alphabetically ascending by name. To do this, you must create a Checker class that implements the Comparator interface, then write an int compare(Player a, Player b) method implementing the Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2) method.

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.name, self.score))

    def comparator(a, b):
        if a.score>b.score:
            return True
        if(a.score==b.score):
            return a.name<b.name
        return False



n = int(input())
data = []
for i in range(n):
    name, score = input().split()
    score = int(score)
    player = Player(name, score)
    data.append(player)

data = sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(Player.comparator))
for i in data:
    print(i.name, i.score)
```

```
Input:
5
amy 100
david 100
heraldo 50
aakansha 75
aleksa 150

Expected Output:
aleksa 150
amy 100
david 100
aakansha 75
heraldo 50

Actual Output:
amy 100
david 100
heraldo 50
aakansha 75
aleksa 150
```

Comment: Your instructions look like they're C++-like, but you're writing in Python. You don't implement any interface named `Comparator`, nor any method named `compare`...

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison function is wrong, per the docs for `cmp_to_key` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key):

> A comparison function is any callable that accept two arguments, compares them, and returns a negative number for less-than, zero for equality, or a positive number for greater-than.

Your `comparator` function returns boolean True or False, you can rewrite it to the required specs by:

```
def comparator(a, b):
    lhs = (-a.score, a.name)  # negating score to sort descending
    rhs = (-b.score, b.name)
    if lhs == rhs:
        return 0
    elif lhs < rhs:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

**update:**
As @ShadowRanger points out, the comparison function can be written more efficiently as:

```
def comparator(a, b):
    lhs = (-a.score, a.name)  # negating score to sort descending
    rhs = (-b.score, b.name)
    return lhs > rhs or -(lhs < rhs)
```

To understand why/how this works, you'll need to know that in Python `bool` is a subclass (and subtype) of `int` and that `False` is defined as `0` and `True` is defined as `1` (from PEP-0285):

```
False = int.__new__(bool, 0)
True = int.__new__(bool, 1)
```

which means that you can do "weird" stuff like:

```
>>> True + 1
2
>>> -True
-1
>>> -False
0
```

so if `lhs > rhs` (and we should return `1`), then the marked part

```
return lhs > rhs or -(lhs < rhs)
       ^^^^^^^^^
```

is `True` (`1`) and the the righ side of the `or` will not be executed -- we return `1` as needed.

If `lhs < rhs` (and we should return `-1`), then the marked part above will be `False` and since `False or x == x` we're left with:

```
return -(lhs < rhs)
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Where the marked part is `True`:

```
return -(True)
```

from above `-True` is `-1`, which is what we wanted to return for this case.

If `lhs == rhs` (and we should return `0`), we get

```
return False or -(False)
```

`False or x` is still `x`, so this leaves:

```
return -(False)
```

Which, from above, is `0`.

**note:** it isn't common anymore to see these types of functions in Python, now you'd normally define `__lt__` and `__eq__` on your class and use the `total_ordering` decorator from `functools` (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

Comment: Note: You could simplify slightly by replacing the `if/elif/else` with just `return lhs > rhs or -(lhs < rhs)`. That returns `True` (1) immediately if `lhs` is greater, falling back to negating `lhs < rhs` to get 0 or -1 otherwise. The canonical one-liner from C would be `return (lhs > rhs) - (lhs < rhs)`, which does get the smallest Python bytecode, and consistently returns a true `int` (if that matters to you for some reason), but C compilers can optimize that construction to compare only once, where Python can't, `lhs > rhs or -(lhs < rhs)` avoids a second comparison roughly half the time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right and I've updated my answer with a little bit more in-depth version of your explanation ;-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger  shorter still (at least in bytecode) `return b.score - a.score or cmp(a.name, b.name)`  and almost 30% faster -- maybe cheating a little bit, but just calling `return cmp(lhs, rhs)` is the slowest version. The original if-version is second fastest, by just barely over 1% in my tests...

Comment: The `cmp` part is an issue given it's Py2 only, which is a dead language at the end of this year (also, the OP tagged their post for Py3).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a comparator function (or it could be much simpler if you want one) because Python will compare tuples hierarchically.

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda p:(-p.score,p.name))
```

Answer (score -1):

I just replace comparator function to this. It worked.

```py
def comparator(a, b):
        if a.score > b.score:
            return -1
        elif a.score < b.score:
            return 1
        elif a.score == b.score:
            if a.name > b.name:
                return 1
            elif a.name < b.name:
                return -1
            else:
                return 0
```

Comment: As a rule, whenever you can, Python comparators should delegate to `tuple`'s comparison functionality whenever possible. The only real exception to that rule is if it's expensive to load the second, third, fourth, etc. attributes to compare on (e.g. they're actually backed by properties that perform meaningful work to compute them). `tuple` comparisons are fast (implemented in C) and implementing lexicographic comparisons by hand is *really* easy to get wrong (and even when you get it right, every maintainer will look at this code and think "Did they really mean to do that?" w/o comments).